# Converting time into readable time with moments, I need keep counting up and down

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm converting time to a readable format 00:02:03.

I need to keep counting up for some cases and down for others by also showing the seconds.

As stated, I'm able to convert the time however I just need to know how to keep counting up and down.

Any ideas?

```js
var timeTarget = $('.time'); // el
var myTime = 123; // seconds

readableTime(timeTarget, myTime)

function readableTime(timeTarget, myTime) {
  setInterval(function() {
    var timeInSeconds = myTime;
    var formattedDur = moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00").add(timeInSeconds, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss");
    timeTarget.html(formattedDur);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<span class="time"><span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment `myTime`, here in snippet I have used postfix `++` operator.

```
var timeInSeconds = myTime++;
```

```js
var timeTarget = $('.time'); // el
var myTime = 123; // seconds

readableTime(timeTarget, myTime)

function readableTime(timeTarget, myTime) {
  setInterval(function() {
    var timeInSeconds = myTime++;
    var formattedDur = moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00").add(timeInSeconds, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss");
    timeTarget.html(formattedDur);    
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<span class="time"><span>
```

Comment: I also need to count down, would I simply just - 1 form the current timer

Comment: @edward, Can you elaborate the problem? yes simply just `- 1`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I would also like to count down sometimes as in 2:03, 2:02, 2:01 etc. Hope I have cleared that up

Comment: @edward, yes  `myTime--` will do

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.